# React-timestamp issue. Can't resolve 'react' in node modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm creating an App with React and everything has been fine for weeks until I installed **react-timestamp** with npm in order to convert unix time (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-timestamp).

But now it won't compile and says: 
`/Users/nembokid/node_modules/react-timestamp/lib/timestamp.js`

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/nembokid/node_modules/react-timestamp/lib'`

I've tried to remove package-lock.json as well as yarn.lock, then did `npm install` again followed by `npm run start`, but still same issue. Also tried to add it to my package.json file, but without success.

In `'/Users/nembokid/node_modules/react-timestamp/lib'` there's only one file: *timestamp.js*. Should it also contain a file called *react.js*?

How can I get around this? Should I try to delete react-timestamp from my node_modules folder? Don't really understand the issue here. Would be grateful for all help!

**Edit:** *package.json*:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.37"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `package.json` file? And to answer your first question, no `react-timestamp` shouldn't include `react`, it's marked as a peer dependency which means it would expect it to be installed already.

Comment: Sometimes running npm install again - or rm -rf node_modules && npm install resolves these kinds of issues (for me anyway)

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious, but if you "installed react-timestamp with npm", shouldn't react-timestamp be in your package.json dependencies?

Comment: @AndyJ Thought the same and tried to add it manually, but it didn't work out :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the folder `/Users/nembokid/node_modules/react-timestamp` and then from the terminal, inside the project client folder: `npm run start` without `npm install` or anything. Works perfectly fine again.